# Show only three Element in Table

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to show only three rows of an HTML table?

The other elements will be visible as you scroll a scrollbar.

Comment: No, Use JavaScript.

Comment: thank's. Can you tell me how ?

Comment: Is it 3 columns or 3 rows ?

Comment: This question is unclear. Do you want the table's height to be such that 3 rows are displayed at a time or only 3 of the rows to be visible irrespective of the height?

Comment: 3 rows displayed at the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your table inside the following `div`.

```
div {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px; /*make this as the height for 3 rows*/
    overflow: scroll;
}
```